# Drag and drop images from toolbar to view canvas

Tags: iphone, ipad, drag-and-drop, drawing

I want to make a app where I need to have a toolbar. The toolbar will have various number of objects (images). These objects should be draggable and placed on view right above it.

This is a kind of drawing app where user can pick any shape and place on canvas. Can anyone tell me the best to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tough one.

What I would do is make each item on the toolbar a UIView and override touchesBegan, touchesEnded, and touchesMoved. Make your canvas another UIView. When a user clicks an item to drag, register that item somewhere, say a square. then when they drop on the canvas, draw that square at that location. To make it look pretty, would probably make a UIImageView with an alpha of like .4 to move with the user's touch, so they know what they are dragging, and where it will land.

Here is the code.
UIViewController.h

```
@class ToolBox;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIView *canvas;

    IBOutlet ToolBox *toolBox;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *canvas;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ToolBox *toolBox;

@end
```

UIViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ToolBox.h"
#import "Tool.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize canvas, toolBox;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[self toolBox] setCanvas:[self canvas]];

    Tool *tool = [[[Tool alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,64,64)] autorelease];
    [tool setImageView:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]] autorelease]];
    [tool setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [tool addSubview:[tool imageView]];
    [tool setToolBox:[self toolBox]];

    [[self toolBox] addObject:tool];
}

@end
```

ToolBox.h

```
@class Tool;
@interface ToolBox : UIView {
    NSMutableArray *tools;

    UIView *canvas;

    UIImage *currentTool;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *currentTool;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tools;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *canvas;

-(void)addObject:(Tool *)newTool;
-(void)updatePositions;

@end
```

ToolBox.m

```
@implementation ToolBox
@synthesize tools, canvas, currentTool;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    [super dealloc];
}

-(NSMutableArray *)tools {
    if(tools == nil) {
        [self setTools:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }

    return tools;
}

-(void)addObject:(Tool *)newTool {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(draggingTool:) name:@"Dragging New Tool" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(draggedTool:) name:@"Dragged Tool To" object:nil];
    [[self tools] addObject:newTool];

    [self updatePositions];
}

-(void)updatePositions {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = 64;
    int height = 64;

    for(Tool *button in [self tools]) {
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        x += width;
        [self addSubview:button];
    }
}

-(void)draggingTool:(NSNotification *)notif {
    NSDictionary *dict = [notif userInfo];  

    UIImage *image = [dict valueForKey:@"Image"];

    [self setCurrentTool:image];
}

-(void)draggedTool:(NSNotification *)notif {
    UITouch *touch = [[notif userInfo] valueForKey:@"Touch"];   

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:canvas];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:currentTool] autorelease];
    [imageView setCenter:point];
    [canvas addSubview:imageView];
}

@end
```

Tool.h

```
@class ToolBox;

@interface Tool : UIView {
    UIImageView *imageView;
    UIImage *image;

    UIImageView *ghostImageView;

    ToolBox *toolBox;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *ghostImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ToolBox *toolBox;

@end
```

Tool.m

```
#import "Tool.h"
#import "ToolBox.h"

@implementation Tool
@synthesize imageView, image, ghostImageView, toolBox;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"tool touches began");
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self image] forKey:@"Image"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Dragging New Tool" object:nil userInfo:dict];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint center = [touch locationInView:[[self toolBox] canvas]];

    [self setGhostImageView:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self image]] autorelease]];
    [[self ghostImageView] setCenter:center];
    [[[self toolBox] canvas] addSubview:[self ghostImageView]];

    [[self ghostImageView] setAlpha:.4];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"tool touches ended");
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[touches anyObject] forKey:@"Touch"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Dragged Tool To" object:nil userInfo:dict];

    [self setGhostImageView:nil];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"tool touch moved");
    if([self ghostImageView] != nil) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint center = [touch locationInView:[[self toolBox] canvas]];
        NSLog(@"Ghost : %2f, %2f", center.x, center.y);
        [[self ghostImageView] setCenter:center];
    }
}

@end
```

My Program came out like this -

Initial screen: The tool is ready to be dragged and dropped onto the canvas

[image: Tool ready to be dragged and dropped]

Dropped the tool on the canvas

[image]

And here is the ghost for the transition

[image]

Comment: I am a new developer, so if you can really guide me that would be great.

Comment: Ok, yea, that was really tough. The problem is with the structure of the touch events. Anyway, here is some code that should get you going. If you need help understanding anything, just comment, i can also send you the project I made.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how this would be implemented in objective c, but I have done almost exactly what you are describing in java. Basically, when you begin to drag the object in the toolbar, it will recognize the action and store a new instance of the item in what I call a transfer container, which is basically a global static variable. That way when the drag action competes (I.e. drops) you can just grab that object from the container and add it to wherever it was dropped.